# Does discrete video card use motherboard monitor connector too?

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, discrete-graphics

I have `Gigabyte GA-B85M-D3H` motherboard (MB) with installed `GTX770` discrete video card. Both MB and video card have sockets to connect monitors.

Are these sockets equivalent?

For example, if I play resource-consuming 3D game on a monitor, connected to MB, will it display what discrete card draws? I.e. can discrete card "draw" to a monitor, connected to MB?

Apparently the answer is "yes", but I wish explicit confirmation.

**UPDATE**

If the answer is "no" then how can I control this? For example, if I run a video game,  how do I tell this game to use discrete graphics?

Operating system (Windows) does not distinguish video cards. In settings I have two monitors and can setup them to display one big desktop. No any setting to select video card.

**UPDATE 2**

I can even play movie and drag window so that it shows partially on one screen and partially on another.

In this case half a video will be displayed by one card and another half by another?

[image]

Comment: Nope the discrete video card will 'draw' what it displays using its GPU which will increase its performance, the MB one does not use this GPU as its not part of the MB so will use its only chipset that will be slower.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running two graphics cards (non-SLI) to power 3D on two different monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/149208/running-two-graphics-cards-non-sli-to-power-3d-on-two-different-monitors)

Answer (score 1):

No the motherboard video will be tied to whatever video chip is utilized in your CPU.  Your discrete video card is completely separate from the motherboard video.  If you plug in your monitor to your motherboards video connections, you will draw whatever the CPU video chip is capable of, and same with the discrete video card, if you have a monitor plugged in, you will draw whatever it is capable of.

They are 2 completely separate entities, and therefore do not really work together, but they work by themselves.  So you'll always want to use your discrete card for graphics intensive work.

Comment: See my update then. How video game knows, what card to use?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting article here regarding how Windows handles it: [Maybe it’s time to talk about a new Linux Display Driver Model](http://www.yosoygames.com.ar/wp/2015/09/maybe-its-time-to-talk-about-a-new-linux-display-driver-model/)

> Let’s take a moment to appreciate how I can plug one monitor to my Radeon HD 7770, another to my integrated Intel HD 4400; and place the window in the middle of the two monitors and still being rendered perfectly fine by any of the two cards, with proper VSync!